# Changing table title from Table to (chapternumber.sectionnumber.tablenumber)

Tags: captions

Instead of my table having the title Table 1.1.8: My table, i need it to have title simply (1.1.8) with no caption (like numbering a table in a math book). How can i achieve this?

Comment: There are two answers by now, but we are just guessing what you want to achieve and what your setup is.  If you want something more specific, please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228).

Comment: Please consider to accept Henri Menke's answer -- he was the first one to answer and provided a somewhat 'cleaner' solution

Comment: Ena: I said `Henri's answer`, not mine ;-)

Comment: I know, i know xD both of you helped so thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `chngcntr` package to change the numbering to depend on the chapter and section.  Use the `caption` to change the format of the caption.

```
\documentclass{book} % we need \chapter
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{table}{section} % number like chapter.section.table
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup[table]{
  justification=raggedleft, % align to the right
  singlelinecheck=false,    % always align
  labelformat=parens,       % add parentheses around number
  labelsep=none,            % remove colon
  textformat=empty,         % suppress caption text
  name={}                   % remove ``Table''
}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{cc}
    a & 1 \\
    b & 2 \\
  \end{tabular}
  \caption{My table}
  \label{tab:mytable}
\end{table}
As seen in table~\ref{tab:mytable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: (+1) (I stole your caption setup ;-))

Comment: thanks Henri, big help, can i push it to the right side? so it is not centered underneath but to the right margin

Comment: @Ena See updated answer.

Comment: If the `caption` package is used anyway one could load it with option `tablewithin` to get rid of needing `chngcntr` as extra package: `\usepackage[tablewithin=section]{caption}`.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Henri's solution, but using `\@addtoreset` instead of `\counterwithin`. I show a different way by not using a `float` and applying `\captionof` instead.

```
\documentclass{book} % we need \chapter

\makeatletter
\@addtoreset{table}{section}
\makeatother

\usepackage{caption}

\captionsetup[table]{%
  textformat=empty,   % suppress caption text
  labelformat=parens, % add parentheses around number
  labelsep=none,      % remove colon
  name={}             % remove ``Table''
}

\usepackage{cleveref}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Foo}
\section{Foobar}

\setcounter{table}{17}

In \cref{nicesttable} we will see the most important table ever

\begingroup
  \centering

  \begin{tabular}{*{3}c}
    a & b & c\tabularnewline
    d & e & f\tabularnewline
  \end{tabular}
  \captionof{table}{A nice table}
  \label{nicesttable}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

Comment: You might want to use `\begin{center}...\end{center}` instead of `\begingroup\centering...\endgroup` (+1).

Comment: @HenriMenke: Thanks, I decided to prevent the vertical extra spacing introduced by the `center` environment`